SQL find lowest value not found in two tables
I want to find the lowest missing number from two tables
For Example,
Table1 columna has 1,2,3,8 
Table2 columnb has 4,10,11

I want to return 5

I have been able to get the lowest missing number from one table, i.e. 4 from Table1, but every time I try to join or compare to another table all I can manage is to get the next 'available' number, i.e. 12.
my sql code:
WITH MissingValues AS (
    SELECT a.bidder_number + 1 AS missing_value
    FROM bidder a
    LEFT JOIN bidder b ON a.bidder_number + 1 = b.bidder_number
    WHERE b.bidder_number IS NULL
     AND a.auctionid = 1)
SELECT MIN(missing_value) AS lowest_missing_value
FROM MissingValues

WHERE missing_value NOT IN ( 
     SELECT permanent_biddernumber FROM customer
     WHERE permanent_biddernumber > 0 AND permanent_biddernumber IS NOT NULL);


I want to find the lowest missing number from two tables, what if there is no missing row ? For example you have 12345 and 8910, what happen in this scenarios ? Or you have 12345 , 8911 , what should be the expected result ?

If there is no missing row, or number, then I would expect to get the next 'available' number not in the columns. For example, t1 has 1,2,3, and t2 has 4,5,6 then I would want to get 7.

1 has 1,2,3, and t2 has 4,5,6 then I would want to get 7 , this changes completely the question

I personally find it easier to use a left join to get a row (missing consecutive number in this case) which does not meet the join condition.
Here are the base tables which are populated with data.
create table Table1 (num int);
create table Table2 (num int);

insert Table1 values(1),(2),(3),(8);
insert Table2 values(4),(10),(11);

First, we make a union table from the base tables.
select num from Table1
union
select num from Table2;

Then we add a row number(rowid) based on the ascending order of num to the union table. This will be the main table we are going to use in the form of a CTE table.
select row_number() over (order by num) rowid, num 
from 
(select num from Table1
union select num from Table2) tu
;

result :
+-------+------+
| rowid | num  |
+-------+------+
|     1 |    1 |
|     2 |    2 |
|     3 |    3 |
|     4 |    4 |
|     5 |    8 |
|     6 |   10 |
|     7 |   11 |
+-------+------+

Finally, we perform a self (left) join using the main table. The join condition is based on the row number(rowid) and the num values, on which the first table(c1)'s rowid +1 must equal the second table(c2)'s row_id ,and c1's num +1 equals c2's num. If the join condition fails, that means the num's continualness is broken. And c1.num + 1 is the missing number. Here is the complete query:
with c as (select row_number() over (order by num) rowid, num 
            from (select num from Table1
                  union
                  select num from Table2) tu
            )
select (c1.num +1) as missing_num 
from c c1 
left join c c2
on c1.rowid +1 = c2.rowid and c1.num + 1= c2.num
where c2.num is null
order by c1.rowid
limit 1 -- removing the limit clause will get all missing numbers
;

result:
+-------------+
| missing_num |
+-------------+
|           5 |
+-------------+


You can do this pretty simply, by using UNION ALL to union the two tables, then use LEAD to check if the next value for each row is exactly one more.
WITH unioned AS (
    SELECT t1.id
    FROM Table1 t1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT t2.id
    FROM Table2 t2
),
WithLead AS (
    SELECT u.*,
      LEAD(u.id) OVER (ORDER BY u.id) AS NextId
    FROM unioned u
)
SELECT
  p.id + 1 AS FirstMissing
FROM WithLead p
WHERE (p.NextId > p.id + 1 OR p.NextId IS NULL)
ORDER BY
  p.id
LIMIT 1;

This results in only a single merged scan of both tables and no joins, and assuming there are indexes there will be no sorts either.
db<>fiddle

TOP (1) * , I guess a typo since you mostly might be using SQL Server. Still it doesn't give the correct result https://dbfiddle.uk/n3DoQ5PB

You're quite right, I needed LEAD not LAG and the output should show the next ID after the current one.

If I change the data it still does not give the expected result, see here, you need the lowest missing not the first one. Based on the OP request the output should be 6 not 4. Maybe the optimal way is to separately find the lowest missing number and compare at the end

Sorry I don't understand why would it be 6? 4 is the first missing number counting upwards?

It's not clear whether they want 4 or 6, the question can be read both ways.


I first generate a series of numbers till the max of from both tables.This gives you all the numbers in numbers CTE
Then those numbers are compared with the values present in both tables and the min is choosen.

Fiddle
WITH RECURSIVE numbers AS (
    SELECT 1 AS num
    UNION ALL
    SELECT num + 1
    FROM numbers
    WHERE num < (SELECT MAX(GREATEST(t1.columna, t2.columnb)) 
                 FROM Table1 t1, Table2 t2)
)
SELECT MIN(num) AS lowest_missing
FROM numbers
WHERE num NOT IN (SELECT columna FROM Table1
                  UNION 
                  SELECT columnb FROM Table2)
LIMIT 1;


I would suggest find every missing row for each table separately and then get the min missing one on both tables
SELECT MIN(missingNumber) as minMissingNumber
FROM(
        (
            WITH RECURSIVE sequence_generator AS (
              SELECT MIN(id) AS n
              FROM Table1
              UNION ALL
              SELECT n + 1
              FROM sequence_generator
              WHERE n < (SELECT MAX(id) FROM Table1)
              )
               SELECT n AS missingNumber
               FROM sequence_generator
               WHERE n NOT IN (SELECT id FROM Table1)
               ORDER BY missingNumber DESC LIMIT 1
        )
        UNION ALL
        (
            WITH RECURSIVE sequence_generator AS (
              SELECT MIN(id) AS n
              FROM Table2
              UNION ALL
              SELECT n + 1
              FROM sequence_generator
              WHERE n < (SELECT MAX(id) FROM Table2)
              )
               SELECT n AS missingNumber
               FROM sequence_generator
               WHERE n NOT IN (SELECT id FROM Table2)
               ORDER BY missingNumber ASC LIMIT 1
        ) 
    ) x;

See example

Note

If there is no missing row, or number, then I would expect to get the
next 'available' number not in the columns. For example, t1 has 1,2,3,
and t2 has 4,5,6 then I would want to get 7

Above answer will return null since there is no missing row
